# SwingWorker extended class not showing overided methods

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, event-dispatch-thread

Here is my sample code... I am facing problem that my swingWorker extended class is only showing doInBackground() to me as overided method. I want to use done() and process() methods also but my class is not showing it @overided nor calling done/process method where it is required to call leave the while loop stuff etc. because I know it is infinite loop but why not the process method is called upon publish()?

```
 public class getChatSwingWorkerThread extends SwingWorker<String , String> {
 private final JTextArea chat_text_area;
 private PostDataConnection post = null;
 private BasicUserInterface chatWindow = null;

public getChatSwingWorkerThread(JTextArea text_area){
    chatWindow = new BasicUserInterface();
    this.chat_text_area = text_area;
    post = new PostDataConnection();
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
    String returnData = "";
    while(true){
        returnData = post.getAvailableChat();
        if(!returnData.equals("")){
            publish(returnData);
            }
       } 

}
protected void process(String returnData) {

    chat_text_area.append(returnData);
}

 public void done(String returnData) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
    chat_text_area.append(get());
}
```

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: Sure brother why not i will definitely focus on it for next time.

Comment: brother,here is brother not sister...lol  :-)

Comment: *"i will definitely focus on it for next time."*  I will definitely read your question next time.  Us sisters got to stick together huh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because your `process` and `done` method have a different signature then the one in the super class.

The signature for the `process` method is

```
protected void process(List<V> chunks)
```

which in your case comes down to

```
protected void process(List<String> chunks)
```

The `done` method does not have any parameters

```
protected void done()
```

Comment: I'd be describe about EDT v.s. doInBackground and methods mentioned in your answer, anyway +1

Comment: @Robin....Thanks a lot...Every new day new error occurs you have new things to learn.!!!